# I need to avoid reloading the page when clicking tag <a>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, single-page-application

I'm creating a SPA with React and need to avoid reloading the page when clicking tag `<a>` or find a way to pass an id to scroll on another "page" to the  tag.

`<Link to="/proyectos" className="cajaCinco"> <h2 className="title">Experiencias</h2> </Link>`

Comment: the code you posted seem incomplete?

Comment: What is `Link`? Is it a styled-component `<a>` element? Is it from React Router? is it something else?

Comment: Link is from React-Router-Dom, i working with V 6.2.1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code example looks incomplete, but generally to prevent events from performing their default action, you would use [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

For example:

```
<a onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()} />
```

Comment: After it was published I realized that the code was not completely uploaded, it is already fixed. Thanks! about your response, i tried with a non arrow function in event onClick and not works, will try with the arrow function now.

Comment: when i clicking ```<a>``` and have the onClick= {(e)=>e.preventDefault()} the tag not redirect to "contactame"

Comment: You do NOT wan the page to reload, but you still want the page to move to the contact form? Do you expect something like a dynamic load of the page, but no URL change?

Comment: something like this, i need to change the url but without the browser load or reload the page, the react router dom allow to show one or other component depending the url

Comment: if the page reload, i lose my redux global state (i using that for a themeselector)